# SSIS scheduled job does not retain command line changes

Tags: sql-server, command-line, ssis, sql-agent-job

I changed all my `PackageProtection` settings in my SSIS packages to `EncryptWithPassword`.

This means that i have to change my command line parameters on the SQL agent job that runs them, and put the password with the /DECRYPT switch.

I just did that. Created a job like:

```
/****** Object:  Step [Load Staging]    Script Date: 14/10/2014 13:02:20 ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Load Staging', 
        @step_id=3, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=3, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        @command=N'/DTS "\"\File System\INT02-LoadStaging\"" /SERVER appsrv02 /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E /DECRYPT xxxxxxx', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=8
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
```

When i run the script the job is created , but when i go to see the command line it still is in the default setting.

I run the job and i get an error for my data sources password.

I have read that it is a bug in older SQL versions where you cannot alter the command line through SSMS, and that is the reason that i created through script.

Is there anything can do or i will have to enable package configuration files for all my packages?

Comment: Are you sure you don't in fact want `sp_update_jobstep`?

Comment: Of course i need..this is just the portion of the job parameters...

Comment: I mean: you are using `sp_add_jobstep`. To change an existing step in an existing job, you need to use `sp_update_jobstep`. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean by "it's still in the default setting". What default, if the job is created fresh? Can you be more specific there?

Comment: The exmaple i have given is with a totally new test-job..I just create it as i show above ,having included the appropriate DECRYPT switch..But it is created with default command line...

Comment: `sp_add_jobstep` doesn't care about the contents of your step, it will simply put it in as-is. Can you try scripting out your job after creating it and checking the result of that? It should be the same as what you put in. Do not use Management Studio, because the bugs are still there -- it is still not reliable to check or edit the job settings, even in SQL Server 2012 (haven't verified 2014 yet). In short, try just running your job and ignore whatever SSMS tells you.

Comment: It seems that you are right my friend..please put it as an answer to accept it...I am running the job now after i exported all steps and added the /DECRYPT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing SSIS job details through Management Studio is unfortunately not reliable -- I've personally had trouble with round-tripping complicated command lines that contain escaped strings (`/CONNECTION "\"name with spaces\"";`) where the command line is simply mangled when you open it, and this mangled version is what gets saved back if you click "OK".

That particular problem appears to have been fixed in SSMS 2014, but it's still true that the editor will parse the command line and rebuild it according to what it thinks is correct, silently discarding options it doesn't like. You can work around this by only scripting job modifications directly and not using the editor, or (I suppose) sink effort into how it thinks you should be doing things instead and stick to that. I personally prefer the former, but I should add that I have no experience using encryption, so for all I know using `/DECRYPT` might be a bad idea -- the general point stands, though.

Comment: Ms officially proposes that if you choose to save sensitive data in package you will have to alter the command line parameters in agent definition. Another option is not to save sensitive data in package and use package configuration files. But what you say stands true..I scripted the job and just run it and it worked.